# download/imprimir arquivo gravado no banco postgresql com php

Tags: php, postgresql

Fiz o upload de um arquivo para o banco postgresql com o tipo de coluna OID.
Com o código abaixo consigo visualizar/abrir o arquivo no browser, mas pretendo fazer download e/ou imprimir esse mesmo arquivo na impressora com php. Os arquivos serão de qualquer extensão.

```
$query= pg_query($dbconn,"select * from tabela") or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
$queryRow= pg_fetch_assoc($query);
$file = $queryRow['doc'];

pg_query($dbconn, "begin");
$handle = pg_lo_open($dbconn, $file, "r");
pg_lo_read_all($handle);
pg_query($dbconn, "commit");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
// consulta postgresql
$query = pg_query($dbconn,"select *, encode(lo_get(arquivo),'base64') as arquivo1 from tabela where id = 1") or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
$queryRow = pg_fetch_assoc($query);

// link para download
<a download="arquivo.png" href="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $queryRow['arquivo1'];?>">Download</a>
```